# How to choose correct .dll files for php extension?

Tags: php, xdebug

In PHP, we use .dll files for different extensions. These are specific for the usage. Multiple **.dll** files exists by default. 
Sometimes for the specific requirements, we need to enable or add extension and place .dll files in the extension directory. In this case, we found there are multiple sources and multiple versions of same .dll file. We choose correct extension by using **hit and trial method** only. Some of these versions are for thread safe PHP while some are for non-thread safe PHP.

```
Why there is no fix pattern and single source of a particular extension?
```

For example, if we search .dll file for xdebug extension, we can see multiple versions for every version of PHP:

```
http://www.xdebug.org/download.php
```

If I am using 32 bit system (windows 2003 - service pack 2). My PHP version is 5.2.17 and apache version is 2.2.22.

- How will I identify the correct php_xdebug.dll file?
- What is thread safe PHP and non-thread safe PHP and how extensions    (.dll files) are related with them?
- Is there any fix pattern to identify the correct .dll file?

Many Thanks :)

Comment: **Side note:** PHP 5.2 is prehistoric. Please update to at least **PHP 5.4**.

Comment: ok, I will do. But, this question is not specific for php 5.2 only.

Comment: **Side note:** Please develop on *NIX, then you won't have this problem. `./configure; make install` ;)

Comment: Why separate files: because it is a PITA when you have both 64-bit code and 32-bit code entry points in the same file, and both thread-safe and non-thread-safe versions of code in the same file; not to mention that the file will be about 4 times the size, and you'll only ever use 25% of the code in that file

Comment: If you know you're using 32-bit Windows, you should be using 32-bit PHP, and phpinfo() will tell you if you're using thread-safe or non-thread-safe PHP, so it should be fairly easy to identify the right file to download

Comment: But, thread safe and non-thread safe is not written anywhere on the page where .dll are available.

Comment: Look for `ts` (thread safe) or `nts` (non thread safe)... If neither is shown, then it's non-thread-safe

Comment: Thanks @MarkBaker. In php.ini file, -ts is there.

Answer (score 3):

For Xdebug, you can choose the wizard to select the good version for your system : 
http://xdebug.org/wizard.php by pasting the resut of your php.ini (php -i >result.txt)

But in general, you should compil these dll with your version of Php. Otherwise, website propose usually different version : 
- Tread safe and Non tread safe
- x86 and x64
- Version of Php 5.2, 5.3,5.4,5.5,...

***For TS and NTS :***

```
Apache + LoadModule: Thread Safe
Apache + FastCGI: Non-Thread Safe
IIS: Thread Safe
IIS + FastCGI: Non-Thread Safe
```

***For x84 and x64***

```
check out if you have c:\program files(x86) = 64bits
```

***For version of Php***

```
- in command line : php -v
```

Once you have all these information, you can choose your Dll but in my experience, it won't work 100% of the time (because of minor releases of php)

The best way is to compile it by yourself especially if it's for a production environment (but who will set a windows Php on prod ????)